# Is there any reason to seal/waterproof underground spliced sprinkler cable?

Tags: waterproofing, sprinkler-system, cables, splicing

Since there isn't an electrical current going through sprinkler wire, it's just a single pulse that gets sent from the controller to the individual valve, is there any reason to waterproof crimp underground sprinkler cable after it's been cut in repair.

[image]

If the answer is No, Then why?

If the answer is Yes, Do you have any suggestions how best to seal and/or waterproof the spliced cable.

Thanks!

Comment: Your contention that "there isn't an electrical current going through sprinkler wire, it's just a single pulse that gets sent from the controller to the individual valve" is **incorrect**. The controller sends low voltage current (commonly 24vt) to the sprinkler valve solenoid for the entire duration of the set activation time for that station.

Comment: Interesting! didn't know that. does it depend on the type of controller or all of them send low voltage current?

Comment: All of them.  Your "pulse" idea would require a much more expensive "latching" magnet valve, I.e. the magnet valve version of a GE RR7 relay, with diodes to allow polarity reversal to confer on/off.  These would also be much more prone to sticking on.

Comment: you can get water resistant connectors

Comment: @jsotola I got butt splice connectors with shrink wrap on the sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because a poor connection due to subsequent corrosion can affect the signal which may well cause unreliable operation.

There are waterproof junction boxes available which you should use.